# On form submit, open a new page in a new tab and redirect the original page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have three pages. Page-1 has a form that when submitted, should open up page-2 in a new tab and page-1 should redirect to page-3.

Right now, clicking submit opens page-2 in a new tab, but it doesn't redirect page-1 unless I already happen to have page-2 open. If page-2 is already open and I click submit, then page-1 redirects to page-3.

How can I get both to occur?

In view template:

```
%button.step1-button.submit{:onClick => "redirect();"} Get Started
```

In controller:

```
@form = FormSubmit.create(:name => name, :form => "/")
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html {redirect_to :page_2}
          format.js { render :action => "redirect()"}
```

In redirect.js:

```
function pop_under2() {
  $('.step1-button').bind("click", function () {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/exit";
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply make the button a link with right href and target set, which has an additional event listener, which submits the form. The controller could redirect afterwards.

Template

```
%a.step1-button.submit.js-submit-form{href: "your_page2_url", target: "_blank"} Get Started
```

Controller

```
@form = FormSubmit.create(:name => name, :form => "/")
redirect_to :page_3
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  $('.js-submit-form').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: This is submitting the form, but it's not redirecting the original to page_3.

Comment: Is the form you are using a remote form? either way, I updated my code

Comment: No, it's not a remote. I got it working by just adding "document.location.href = "/page_3";. Still not sure why the redirect isn't working in the controller, but I think this resolved it.